# Realm invalid type

Tags: java, android, realm

I tried to use Realm to make a wish list in my android app. I put data from adapter to SinglePost Activity and I try to put them in realm and display in another activity.
In SinglePost Activity I got this error!
Here is my Activity

```
public class SinglePost extends AppCompatActivity {
    String id, image, url, content, video;
    Realm realm;
    public Adapter adapter;
    ModelPost postInfo;
    private String postId;
    public static final String Key_Post = "ID";
...
        id = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
        postTitle.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Title"));
        postExpert.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Expert"));
        image = getIntent().getStringExtra("Image");

        postId = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<ModelPost> result = realm.where(ModelPost.class).equalTo(Key_Post, postId).findAll();
        if (result.size() != 0) {
            bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_black_24dp);
        } else {
            bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border_black_24dp);
        }
        Bookmark();
    }

    private void Bookmark() {

        bookmark.setOnClickListener(v -> realm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
            RealmResults<ModelPost> results = realm.where(ModelPost.class).equalTo(Key_Post, id).findAll();
            if (results.size() == 0) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                }
                realm.copyToRealm(postInfo);
                bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_black_24dp);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                results.get(0).deleteFromRealm();
                bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border_black_24dp);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }));
    }
```

Model:

[Model Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1dpp.jpg)

Config:

```
public class G extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
        RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query: field 'ID' in class 'ModelPost' is of invalid type 'INTEGER'.
```

Comment: Please add all relevant code into the post, do not link as a jpg. You haven't said which line has the error, but I'm assuming it's either of the two `realm.where()` lines?

Comment: @ChrisShaw, Hi Chris. Yes. two `realm.where()` lines. But error points to Model Class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retrieving the required ID from the activity intent extras, as a string. Your model type uses an integer for the `ID` field. This is why the types do not match and you are getting an error.

Incidentally, you are creating two variables (`postId` and `Id`) that appear to have identical uses - are you sure you need both? I would keep one of these, but make it an `int` field. The rest of this answer assumes you are keeping `id`.

Firstly, check that this is also how you are adding the value to the intent (i.e. that you are calling `intent.putExtra()` with a string argument and not an integer). If it is an integer, then you can use `getIntExtra()` above instead of `getStringExtra()`, and assign directly to `id`. If it is indeed a string, then you need to convert to an integer as below.

```
String idAsString = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
id = Integer.valueOf(idAsString).intValue();
```

Then all should be good.